# Prove an inequality involving the absolute value of the spatial derivative of the solution to the heat equation.

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

Given the initial value problem $$u_t=ku_{xx}$$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$ $$u(x,0)=f(x)$$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is some square integrable function in $\mathbb{R}$, prove there exist constant $c$ such that $$|u_x| \leq c t^{-3/4} \| f(x) \|$$

My attempt, consider the solution to the heat equation $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \int_{- \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}} f(y)dy$$
If I differentiate it I get $$u_x=\frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \int_{- \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}} \left( \frac{-2(x-y)}{4kt} \right) f(y)dy$$
Now $$|u_x|=\left|\frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \int_{- \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}} \left( \frac{-2(x-y)}{4kt} \right) f(y)dy \right| \leq$$
$$\left( \frac{1}{(4k \pi t)^{1/2}} \int_{- \infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2kt}} \left( \frac{-2(-1)(x-y)}{2kt} \right) \frac{1}{4kt} \right)^{1/2} \| f(x) \|$$
I compute the integral using the error function by letting $z=\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2kt}$ I get that $$|u_x| \leq c t^{-3/2} \| f(x) \|$$ for $$c=\frac{1}{4k (4k \pi )^{1/2}} \left( \frac{\sqrt{ \pi } }{2} \right)^{1/2}$$
But this is wrong since I got a $t^{-3/2}$ factor instead of the desired $t^{-3/4}$.
I spend a lot of time trying to figure out my mistake but couldn't find it.
Can you help me spot my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.
\begin{equation}
u_x(x, t) = -\frac{1}{(4\pi kt)^{1/2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2kt}(x - y)
e^{-(x - y)^2/4kt}\, f(y)\, dy.
\end{equation}
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
\begin{align}
\vert u_x(x, t) \vert
&= \frac{1}{(4\pi kt)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{2kt} \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x - y)
e^{-(x - y)^2/4kt}\, f(y)\, dy \right| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{(4\pi kt)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{2kt} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x - y)^2 e^{-(x - y)^2/2kt}\, dy \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(y) \, dy\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \frac{1}{(4\pi kt)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{2kt} \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty w^2 e^{-w^2/2kt}\, dw\right)^{1/2}\left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(y) \, dy\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
In the integral over $w$ make the change of variable $v = w/\sqrt{kt}$. Then you're left with
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty w^2 e^{-w^2/2kt}\, dw = (kt)^{3/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty v^2 e^{-v^2/2}\, dv.
\end{equation}
Keeping in mind you need the square root of this last relation, start collecting up the powers of $t$ to see that $\vert u_x(x, t) \leq C t^{-3/4} \vert f \vert_{L^2}$.

Revisit how you applied Cauchy-Schwarz. If nothing else you ought to have ended up with a $(x - y)^2$ in the mix.